# px.line_3d appears black screen not showing 3D plot graph

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I have a problem about showing 3D plot graph in plotly.

Here is the screen shown below.

[image]

When I click black part, it directs to webgl.org webpage. It's shown a message.

```
Your browser supports WebGL
You should see a spinning cube. If you do not, please visit the support site for your browser.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It caused by the caches of brower. After cleaning  all caches, its open 3D model.